# cocoa: NSString not removing all the characters

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, nsarray, int

I have an int and for some reason it isn't working after 16 or so.  Here's my code:

```
NSArray *sortedArray; 
sortedArray = [doesntContainAnother sortedArrayUsingFunction:firstNumSort context:NULL];

int count2 = [sortedArray count];
//NSLog(@"%d", count2);
int z = 0;
while (z < count2) {
    NSString *myString = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:z];
    NSString *intstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", z];
    NSString *stringWithoutSpaces; 
    stringWithoutSpaces = [[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:intstring
                                                              withString:@""] mutableCopy];
    [hopefulfinal addObject:stringWithoutSpaces];
    NSLog(@"%@", [hopefulfinal objectAtIndex:z]);
    z++;
}
```

Edit: It's not the int, it's the stringWithoutSpaces line...  I can't figure out what's causing it.

So it (the NSLog, see above the z++) looks like this:

"Here"

"whatever"

"17 whatevere"

"18 this"

etc.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what do you have (your input data) and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: From my understanding of your code, you are translating the char to a string of it's ascii value, then I'm not sure what you are replacing because the line is not complete.

Comment: Why are you making a mutable copy? You don't mutate the string. Plus, you leak it.

Comment: I can see what you're trying to do, but I can't see why it would stop working part way through. My best advice is to use the debugger and see what's really happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is related to your earlier question [Sort NSArray’s by an int contained in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870656/sort-nsarrays-by-an-int-contained-in-the-array/1870703#1870703), and that you're trying to strip the leading number and whitespace from an array that looks like the one you had in that question:

```
"0 Here is an object"
"1 What the heck, here's another!"
"2 Let's put 2 here too!"
"3 Let's put this one right here"
"4 Here's another object"
```

Without know the full input, I'd guess that your code is likely failing because the leading numbers and the value of `z` are getting out of sync. Since you don't seem to actually care what the leading number is and just want to vamoose it, I'd recommend a different approach that scans for leading digits and extracts the substring from the position where those digits end:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1 One",
                                           @"2 Two",
                                           @"5 Five",
                                           @"17 Seventeen",
                                           nil];

NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
NSScanner *scanner;
NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];

for (NSString *item in array) {
    scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:item];
    [scanner scanInteger:NULL]; // throwing away the BOOL return value...
                                // if string does not start with a number,
                                // the scanLocation will be 0, which is good.
    [results addObject:[[item substringFromIndex:[scanner scanLocation]]
                         stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace]];
}

NSLog(@"Resulting array is: %@", results);

// Resulting array is: (
//    One,
//    Two,
//    Five,
//    Seventeen
// )
```

)